# Will the crowning of King Charles have any practical effect on UK government?

Tags: united-kingdom, monarchy, political-transitions

The Queen of England has passed today and it appears that Prince Charles will assume the throne. Will this have any practical effect on their governing or nothing more than a change of figurehead? Is it like the THE WHO's lyric "meet the new boss, same as the old boss" ?

QUESTION: Will the crowning of King Charles have any practical effect on UK government?

Comment: I guess I'd like to know the reasoning of the person downvoting this question within 14 minutes of its posting.   Thanks to @Rick Smith for providing better tags

Comment: I have purposefully NOT included my perceptions of the operations of a constitutional monarchy.

Comment: We already have a question about the political powers of the British monarch. Nothing about that changes now that the United Kingdom has a new monarch.

Comment: "it appears that Prince Charles will assume the throne": he has already become king, instantaneously and automatically, at the moment of his mother's death.

Comment: @Philipp I understand the 'as defined' powers of the monarchy. I was more interested in what might/can/probably will happen in the  "power switchover".  Will there be a lot of sucking up, infighting, reneging?

Comment: @Philipp I just followed the link to the referenced prior question and found that I did indeed read it in full prior to my new post. My question is not "what powers does the monarch have" but rather "what shakeups might result from the transfer of power".

Comment: @phoog In fairness, in the case of a breaking news story it is appropriate to use hedging language because, for example, media accounts could be mistaken about what really happened. It wouldn't have been the first time that news reports declared someone to be dead prematurely, although, a couple of hours later, it seems increasingly clear that the account was correct.

Comment: FWIW, I would not have closed this as a duplicate. The effects are not major, but lots of official documents, currencies, new post office boxes, legal pleadings, etc. which reference the Queen would have to be amended prospectively in a lot of symbolic busywork and there would have to be new images of the monarch put up in government offices, etc. These are minor, but they are "practical effects." I also think that a few things are still reckoned in reginal years which would start over now (not nearly as many as in Japan however).

Comment: More deeply, since QEII has been a steady hand as a monarch for 70 years, there is some lack of clarity as to how much conventional wisdom about what a monarch does is personal to her and how much is attributable to the institution. Charles III doesn't have to follow all of the conventions that QEII did and there are usually some shifts between monarchs regarding the individual's role in the institution that have been forgotten since it hasn't happened for such a long time.

Comment: @BradV What *might* happen is pure speculation. We generally do not allow speculative questions on this website.

Comment: @Philipp In the 'speculation' context I now agree with you. Thanks! I would expect a lot of political pushing, shoving, favor-seeking amongst factions to establish better footing with new guy.

Comment: If you are able to log in to the BBCor another UK media outlet, there has been nothing but wall-to-wall coverage on the Queen, the monarchy, King Charles III, etc., for the last three days - non-stop.  In historical documentaries, news, political discussion programmes etc the matter of the Crown its history and its future has been discussed from every conceivable angle.

Comment: I take it you mean "government" in the US sense? It certainly won't have any effect on who is the PM or the cabinet.

Comment: I suggest removing *Is it like the THE WHO's lyric "meet the new boss, same as the old boss"* - it might be perceived as contemptuous of Charles, or the Monarchy, or the British government.

Comment: There are doubtless a lot of minor incidental effects, like Liz Truss will be less able to present her new policies, and branches of government may choose to "bury bad news" while the media's attention is elsewhere. The suspension of parliament during the mourning period is also a political effect. It's not really clear what kind of effects the question is asking about (which is one reason for downvoting, along with the lack of evidence of research).

Comment: @Acccumulation From context, I think it is clear that it is meant in the U.S. sense (or really, the more general sense; the U.K. the term has one more sense of the word than the U.S. but has always retained the more general sense as well).

Comment: @RogerVadim - as a Brit, I perceive no contempt in the Who quote, at least towards the king or monarchy, only inaccuracy, since a constitutional monarch is not the 'boss'. As regards the actual government, it is a legitimate comment, although I hope Keir Starmer might be a different 'boss'.

Answer (score 9):

Very little.

Bits of paperwork will need to be amended:  It is now "*His* Majesty's Government" and so forth

There are transitional matters to arrange.  The funeral and coronation are state affairs and are organised by the government - and of course members of the government will not be doing other business when they are attended these events.

The Queen has a weekly audience with the Prime Minister.  It is clear that she has not always been well enough to receive the Prime Minister.  Surely the King will want to hold these meetings.

Other matters which had been done by her household or by members of her family will now be done in person by the King. The King will open parliament but he already did this.  Next time, he gets to wear the <s>silly hat</s> crown.

Similarly, the government uses the royals to project soft power: "Be nice to Britain, and we'll let your head of government have dinner with the *King*".  (Trump, for example was flattered by having a State reception with the Queen).  The Queen has been too unwell in recent months to attend such events - which were anyway impossible during the pandemic.  The new King can resume a more active diplomatic role.

Finally, Charles has different priorities and interests from Elizabeth. He is personally much more concerned about the environment, for example.

This is not like the Who lyric, because there is no claim of being radically different.  The Who are criticising politicians who claim to represent radical change, but do nothing.  The monarchy represents continuity not change.

Comment: That's actually significant.

Comment: Will Charles's priorities actually affect the government? There's not much evidence that the late Queen's interests affected government policy.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** but the difference is soft power rather than hard. The Queen, by dint of her long reign and association with meeting with a great many important figures of the past century meant that she was a significant draw for many around the world. Whether you're the President of the US, the Chancellor of Germany, or the Sultan of Brunei, meeting Queen Elizabeth II carried a significance that meeting other royalty around the world didn't to the same extent. King Charles III does not have the same level of cachet that the Queen had, and is unlikely to develop it during his remaining lifespan.

This made the Queen a more powerful tool of diplomacy than King Charles III will be, and that loss of power will weaken the UK's ability to project influence overseas. It is also likely that some of the remaining Commonwealth Realms (those which still have the British monarch as head of state, not to be confused with the wider group of Commonwealth Countries) will change to being Republics now that the Queen has died; this will also reduce British influence.

Of course, we shouldn't exaggerate the importance of this. The UK's influence around the world is grounded much more in it's economy, military, history, and alliances than it is in the Monarchy.

In terms of day-to-day matters, most differences are mere trivia, but it is notable that the PM still meets with the Monarch weekly. What happens at these meetings is entirely secret, but various PMs have commented on the value of these meetings with the Queen, and some of that comes from the Queen's wisdom and knowledge from the decades of these meetings. King Charles III will not have the same experience to draw on, nor are his words likely to carry the same weight with the PM. However, because of the private nature of these meetings it is completely unclear what level of difference this will make.

Comment: Arguably the UK had *already* lost those benefits (with the Queen's ailing health making her unavailable for audiences, whether with foreign dignitaries or the PM,) and as such the crowning of the new King will be an improvement in those respects even if they fall short of what the Queen offered at her height.